# Run "exe" Python3 on Window terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, cx-freeze

I have a simple code with few "print" and "input".
I used cx_freeze to convert my python code on ".exe", but obviously when I launch my exe, it's run in background without any GUI (ofc I don't have GUI).
How to open it on cmd to interact with some "input" and see "print", like I do with my IDE (pycharm) cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to run it as an .exe, or is your goal to just run the script in cmd? To execute an .exe file in cmd, you should be able to just run by entering in the filename while you're in that file's folder directory:

1. Change to directory where program.exe is located by using cd:
   `cd C:\Users\johndoe\folder\`
2. Run the program program.exe `program.exe`

However to save you compiling the python script to a .exe each time, if you already have python installed in your windows and you just want to run the python script, it should work with user inputs in the script by just entering `python` and the python filename (e.g. `pyscript.py`) into the windows cmd like below:

```
python pyscript.py
```

If your python script is a class / function that accepts arguments input1 and input 2:

```
python pyscript.py input1 input2
```